# PDO syntax seems incorrect

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO for the first time.

```
$result=$dbh->query($query) or die($dbh->errorinfo()."\n");

echo $result->fetchColumn();

$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The result of following code is that $row is initilazed ie isset but is empty.

I couldnot get where did I go wrong. thanks in advance

Comment: If your query results in one row, perhaps the `fetchColumn()` is moving your pointer to the end of the resultset.

Comment: So what is the solution? I need fretchColumn to check if the column exissts

Comment: Comment out the `echo $result->fetchColumn();` line.

Comment: echo statement gives me the sno (first column) of row of table which is queried

Comment: `fetchColumn` & `fetch` don't mix well, and keep in mind: once fetched, there is no easy way to 'unfetch' or 'refetch'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO doesn't do the old `mysql_*` style `do or die()` code.

Here's the correct syntax:

```
try {
    //Instantiate PDO connection
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name", "user", "pass");
    //Make PDO errors to throw exceptions, which are easier to handle
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //Make PDO to not emulate prepares, which adds to security
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `some_table`";

    //Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    //Execute it (if you had any variables, you would bind them here)
    $stmt->execute();

    //Work with results
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //Do stuff with $row
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //Catch any PDOExceptions that were thrown during the operation
    die("An error has occurred in the database: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

You should read the **[PDO Manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**, to get better understanding of the subject.

Comment: `PDO` in default errormode (without exceptions) _does_ do the `or die()` code (which is't MySQL specific, `$fp = fopen('somefile') or die('cannot open file);` works equally well. However, everybody knows that `or die()` is about the worst error handling one can thinks of, even a `or trigger_error()` is better, so you are right to steer the OP away from that. However: this does not address the problem: mixing columns & row fetches.